# css images not showing when accessed from sub folder

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

My site directory is like this....

I have a root folder with 4 sub folders. and my html files

images

family

js

css

css has sub folders names ie and images

Every thing works fine until I create a new html file inside the family folder

I get nothing, no images, no formating. If I add ../ I get the formating and a image    `<p><a href="#" class="image full"><img src="../images/pics02.jpg" alt=""></a></p>` but the images from the css-images still dont show. I opened the css file and add ../ to the call for my banner but it still doesnt show? Ive tried combinations of ../ ./ / and every but `http://example.com/css/stylesheet.css`. I thought that last one would make it longer to load.

Here is some code copy and pasted.

Code from family/index.html

```
<script src="../js/skel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/skel-panels.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/init.js"></script>
    <noscript>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/skel-noscript.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" />
    </noscript>
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/ie/v8.css" /><![endif]-->
    <!--[if lte IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/ie/v9.css" /><![endif]-->
```

code from css/style.css

/*********************************************************************************/
/* Header                                                                        */
/*********************************************************************************/

```
#header
{
    position: relative;
    background: #ddd url(../images/header.jpg) no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
}

#logo
{
}

#nav
{
}

    #nav ul
    {
        margin: 0;
    }
```

I cant get that header to show no matter what I try =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding you're trying to access an image in your family folder's file from your css subfolder named images.

In this case you would use

```
"../css/images/header.jpg"
```

If you're trying to access images from your main images folder you would use

```
"../images/header.jpg"
```

And finally if you are trying to access the images from your css file (likely found in the css folder) you would use

```
"images/header.jpg"
```

Look at this link for more details about directories in html
http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/html/links

Answer (score 0):

try this
    `background: #ddd url("../images/header.jpg") no-repeat center;`

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the periods and just use paths like this:

```
/images
/js
```

Answer (score 0):

use only `/` when you want to access css-images and `../` if you want to access parent directory.

`../` is used for one directory up

whereas `/` is root directory

when your current directory is css then your root is `/`